# LabVIEW - writing data from multiple DAQ Assistants in the same .csv-file

Tags: csv, labview

I have the following problem with my VI, which I could not solve by myself or research:

When running the VI, the data should be stored in a .csv-File. In the pictures, you can see the block diagram. When running, it produces the following file:

> Test Steady State
> T_saug_1/T_saug_2/Unbelegt/Unbelegt/T_ND/T_HD/T_Wasser_ein/T_Wasser_aus/T_front/T_back/T-right/T-left
> 18,320 18,491 20,873 20,838 20,463 20,969 20,353 20,543 20,480 20,618
> 20,618 20,238

As you can see, the data gets stored only in the first column (in the preview of the post it looks like it is a row, but it is really a column; T steady state is the header). But these temperatures are not the temperatures of the first sensor, it somehow stored the value for every sensor in the respective row. When the first row was filled, it stopped storing data entirely. I did not figure out how I could insert a file here, otherwise I would have done so... I want to store the data for each sensor in the associated column.

Another problem I have: the waveform-chart, which shows all the temperatures, only updates every 4-6 seconds. Not only is the interval between every update not always the same, but from my understanding it should update every second since the while-loop has a wait-timer set to 1000ms. I don't know what my mistake here is...

Please let me know if you have any ideas on how to solve the problems I have or suggestions where I could find answers to my questions. I am very new to LabVIEW, I am sorry if this question is silly.

With best regards an thank you for the patient help,
lempy.

[csv-file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhW9K.png)

[Block diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIBOB.png)

[DAQ-Assis. for PT100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZMnS.png)

[DAQ-Ass. for TC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkWnp.png)

Comment: You might try using TDMS files instead of CSV. They're binary instead of ASCII, and more robust. The loop timer is not overly precise. A timed loop would give you more precision on timing, particularly if you could tie it to a hardware clock and not a Windows clock.

Answer (score 0):

The `Write Delimited Spreadsheet` VI has two boolean inputs: `Append to file?` and `transpose?`

`Append to file?` is not set for the first write, which defaults to FALSE. That means, on each write, the file is overwritten. For the second and third call, it is set to TRUE, so those data is appended.
The most simple solution is to put the first two write functions outside the main loop. This overwrites the file at start of the VI with the headers, and values will be appended as desired.

`transpose?` will swap rows and columns. Wire TRUE to it, and check if it works.

---

About your second question:
A loop runs as fast as the slowest process inside. If the graph is updated every 6s only, something takes 6s to complete. My guess is that those temperature readings take so long...